# Delete row with ajax and delete the record on page too

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to remove the record in database via ajax. In the same time I want to delete also the record from the page. So I have this in my HTML

```
<ul id="comments-list record-'.$row['id'].'" class="comments-list record">
    <li>
        <div class="comment-main-level">
            <div class="comment-box">
                <div class="comment-head">
                    <h6 class="comment-name by-author">'.$row['author'].''</h6>

                    <a href="?delete='.$row['id'].'" class="del">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash "></i>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is inside the loop which display all records on page. This is the ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.del').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And my delete.php is simple delete query

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM comment where id = :id"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', (int)$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Current error is from the ajax when I click on delete on this line `index.php:183 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

The ajax part is from tutorial since I'm very unfamiliar with js/ajax.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Neither HTML4 nor HTML5 allows space characters in ID attribute values. The HTML 4.01 spec states that ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.)

Comment: @TodorSimeonov thanks. I'm not sure what exactly this means but even if I remove the space in `data` like `data: 'ajax=1&delete='+parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),` still same error appears.

Comment: Your `ul` tag got a space in its ID: `id="comments-list record-'.$row['id'].'"`. I'm not sure if its the problem, but anyway you should fix this too.

Comment: No, it's not the problem. I've made it like this `id="comments-list-record-'.$row['id'].'"` and `.replace('comments-list-record-','')`. Still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `$(this)` = `<a href="?delete='.$row['id'].'" class="del">`.

`var parent = $(this).parent();` = `<div class="comment-head">`
which has no ID. Thus `attr('id')` returns `undefined`.

You can select the `ul` element this way:

```
var parent = $(this).closest('ul.comments-list.record');
```

Comment: Okay. How to select `ul` then>

Answer (score 1):

How about this code: (make full use of jquery)

```
<ul id="comments-list record-'.$row['id'].'" class="comments-list record">
<li>
    <div class="comment-main-level">
        <div class="comment-box">
            <div class="comment-head">
                <h6 class="comment-name by-author">'.$row['author'].''</h6>
                <i onclick="del(<?=$row['id']?>)" class="fa fa-trash "></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

your jquery becomes:

```
function del(i)
  {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            data: {'ajax':1,'delete':i},
            success: function() {
                get_list();
            }
        });
    }

function get_list()
{
 //make ajax call to get data from php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you welcome....if this was the answer then you should mark this as answer

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined because the parent you are fetching is this one:

```
<div class="comment-head">
```

As you can see that does not have an id. That is why you are getting undefined.

For reference, I do not believe that there is a replace() method in jQuery. What you might be looking for is a replaceWith() method. Please refer to the documentation for more information.

I do not believe that you need to do a replace anywhere. From what I can understand, you want to pass the row[id] as a parameter on your AJAX call. Instead of trying to do a replace, use data as shown below:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
        #comments-list {
                border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>

<ul id="comments-list" data-id="1" class="comments-list record">
    <li>
        <div class="comment-main-level">
            <div class="comment-box">
                <div class="comment-head">
                    <h6 class="comment-name by-author">Me</h6>

                    <a href="?delete=1" class="del">
click here
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.del').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Grab the id
        var commentsBlock = $('#comments-list');
        var id = commentsBlock.data('id');
        console.log(id);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + id,
            success: function() {
                commentsBlock.slideUp(300,function() {
                    commentsBlock.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```